# How does one plot an ISO week time series plot in Data Studio that does not begin on Week 1?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to overplot four years of data to see how they compare over a year. I have created a field called *season* to separate the four years and have another field called *week* corresponding to the ISO week. However, I cannot figure out the way to make the plot start at, say, week 31 instead of week 1.

Here is the plot of what I have so far:

[Data Studio ISO week plot starting at week 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPOVj.png)

Is there a way to start the time axis at a different starting week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, Data Studio itself as a visualisation tool does not have the functionality to wrap the dates around as you wish.

One option would be to look to the query/dataset you're using and shift the dates such that (pseudocode):

```
offset = 31
if week >= offset then shift -(offset)   // resets to origin (left shift) 
if week < offset then shift +(52-offset) // resets remaining data (right shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a time series in **Data Studio filter** to begin your ISO Week. I have tried that with YEARWEEK filter and seem to be working fine.

**Here's an example:**

[image: Before Time series filter]

*And now with a time series filter: set to Jan 1st 2017*
[image: filter set to 2017]

If Including (YearWeek) is going to solve your problem then, this is how you do it right from Google Data Studio.

Although, I have to say that when I tried that with `ISO Week(ww)` filter, it doesn't seem to be working fine. My understanding is that, when aggregating time series by ISO Week (ww) it encounters duplicate week numbers: 01, 12, 13 in 'ww' when your plot has more than one year of data. I found `YEARWEEK` to be a possible work around.

Comment: I think you are correct about using YearWeek, but if you want to compare same week (e.g. Week 23) but different years then this filtering doesn't seem to work.

One can create a date using the data's month and day but using a dummy year (e.g. 2016) but then you are stuck with the year showing up in the x-axis and have to consider Feb 29th.

Comment: It actually worked when comparing different years using YEARWEEK filter. I tried that on a timeseries and seems to work. If I am not mistaken though, I think what you're saying is when comparing just week numbers (in format 'ww') for e.g. week '23' it may show an error, which I think is because it tries to aggregate week 23 (from different years). Using YEARWEEK, every yearweek holds a unique data. I haven't figured out how to compare just 'ww' values across years though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by:

1. Clicking on the [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) chart;
2. Switching to the `Style` Tab, scrolling down to the `X-Axis` section;
3. Setting the X-Axis Range to `Range by Data`.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/4b814cc3-397d-444b-ae2c-f01684055d82) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]